# How to use int for DateTime

Tags: c#, api

So, what I am trying to do right now is setting 1:20PM into my DateTime object.
The way I'm doing it is like this (if there is any better way of doing it, please let me know).

```
var hours = requestModel.DateTime.AddHours(1);
var minutes = requestModel.DateTime.AddMinutes(20);
```

As you can see DateTime is a property inside of my requestModel class, so I can't use Parse().

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a DateTime you want, try this:

```
var date = requestModel.Date;
var result = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, date.Day, 1, 20, 0);
```

based on [this constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_DateTime__ctor_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Int32_).

If you want a TimeSpan, try this:

```
var result = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(80);
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! I apologize if my question has not been cleared enough. Can you also give me an example of if I want to use the current real life time instead of setting my own time (1:20pm), please.

EDIT: I guess I just have to write something like "date.Hour, date.Minute" etc. or?

Comment: If you just want the current time, use `var result = DateTime.Now;`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `TimeSpan` or `DateTime.ParseExact` method.

```
var dateTime = DateTime.Now;
        
var timeSpan = new TimeSpan(1, 20, 0);
var result = dateTime.Add(timeSpan);

var timeSpan2 = TimeSpan.Parse("1:20");
var result2 = dateTime.Add(timeSpan2);

var dt = DateTime.ParseExact("1:20pm", @"h\:mmtt",
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AllowInnerWhite);
var result3 = dateTime.Add(dt.TimeOfDay);
```

Comment: @Zagros - I don't understand you. Do you want set "1:20" or add?

Answer (score 0):

What about `var minutes = requestModel.DateTime.AddMinutes(80);`

Comment: @Zagros: Do you want to **set** a *time*, or **add** a *time interval*?  You can't add two times, that's complete nonsense like saying "What is February 7th plus May 19th?"